# How to get the memory size used by a process in Linux?

Tags: linux, memory

i want get the memory size used by a process in Linux. How can I do that?

Comment: `cat /proc/<pid>/status`

Comment: See here, same as macos https://stackoverflow.com/a/41207962/2836621

Answer (score 0):

```
ps aux --sort -rss
```

This will give you a listview of your Prozesses, Wortes by memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

some useful commands to get memory info for a process:

```
pmap -x <PID>
top -p <PID>
```