# How to get the memory usage of a OS X/macOS process

Tags: macos, command

In Ubuntu, `/usr/bin/time -v any-command` tells me the memory usage of `any-command` and some information. 
(Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/774601/2885946)

I want to do the same thing in OS X/macOS.

Could you tell me how to get the memory usage of a process on OS X like `/usr/bin/time -v` in Ubuntu?

Comment: The best way is to just install GNU `time` using homebrew. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515381/mac-os-x-usr-bin-time-verbose-flag/32515486#32515486

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use the Apple-supplied `/usr/bin/time` as follows without installing anything:

```
/usr/bin/time -l <DO SOMETHING>
```

It is important to use the full path `/usr/bin/time` because `time` calls bash and results in error: `-bash: -l: command not found`

**Sample Output**

```
0.04 real         
0.00 user
0.00 sys
   2830336  maximum resident set size       <-- peak memory usage
         0  average shared memory size
         0  average unshared data size
         0  average unshared stack size
       462  page reclaims
       253  page faults
         0  swaps
        13  block input operations
         3  block output operations
         0  messages sent
         0  messages received
         0  signals received
        26  voluntary context switches
        94  involuntary context switches
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your perfect answer!!

Comment: Just in case someone wonders: it's in bytes, unlike on Linux which uses kilobytes.

Answer (score 4):

For me, the next command works great:

```
ps -axm -o %mem,rss,comm | grep <programm name>
```

Comment: Also, you can grep whatever you need, f.e. PID

Comment: For process specific details `ps -xm -o %mem,rss,comm -p $(pgrep <process-name>)` for instance `ps -xm -o %mem,rss,comm -p $(pgrep InDesign)`